# Sometimes I got this error in my app part: The remote server returned an error (401) Unauthorized

Tags: provider-hosted-app, access-denied, adfs

I created an provider hosted app and use SP2013 on-prem and ADFS authentication. I have an app part with some form. This app part is added to a page in a webpart zone. Initial this app part is working. You will see the form and can submit. But when the browser is inactive for example 15 minutes and you go again to the page with the app part, you will get the error:

> The remote server returned an error (401) Unauthorized.

It is not fixed after 15 minutes. It looks like it is random.

[image]

A work around is to log off, and then log in. Then everything is working fine. Is there some cookie/session/token expired period which is doing this behavior?

We implemented [this ADFS implementation](http://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/deploying-adfs3-for-sharepoint-2013-in-a-perimeter-network#.V_9BpOn8K72).

In the ULS I found this information which is related to this error:

> got client_id:
>   i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|0aeb5a99-dcc6-4208-9398-a4fc10272c6b@3a5e94a9-2edd-42b3-9fca-5ef76e45719f
>   and instance_id:
>   https://apps.myCompany.nl/PCDocument/Create?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fbm%2EmyCompany%2Enl&SPHostTitle=myCompany&SPAppWebUrl=""&SPLanguage=nl%2DNL&SPClientTag=1&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4841%2E1000&SenderId=960DD4660
>   from query string.
>
> looking for app instance that matches client_id:
>   i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|0aeb5a99-dcc6-4208-9398-a4fc10272c6b@3a5e94a9-2edd-42b3-9fca-5ef76e45719f
>
> The current user has
>   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name =
>   05.t|adfs|sp-install@dev.com, System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name = NT
>   AUTHORITY\IUSR, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name =
>   05.t|adfs|sp-install@dev.com.
>
> app instance found whose AppPrincipalId matches client_id
>   i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|0aeb5a99-dcc6-4208-9398-a4fc10272c6b@3a5e94a9-2edd-42b3-9fca-5ef76e45719f
>
> redirectLaunUrl after getting it from query string, web or app
>   instance:
>   https://apps.myCompany.nl/PCDocument/Create?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fbm%2EmyCompany%2Enl&SPHostTitle=myCompany&SPAppWebUrl=""&SPLanguage=nl%2DNL&SPClientTag=1&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4841%2E1000&SenderId=960DD4660
>
> trying to get app tokens for site:
>   5998b5cd-6cef-41b4-b36a-eca33cbfbb03 Unable to load app tokens from
>   appInstanceId: 05138aae-7267-455e-a630-a82098a5185e
>
> redirectLaunUrl after getting token replacement:
>   https://apps.myCompany.nl/PCDocument/Create?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fbm%2EmyCompany%2Enl&SPHostTitle=myCompany&SPAppWebUrl=""&SPLanguage=nl%2DNL&SPClientTag=1&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4841%2E1000&SenderId=960DD4660
>
> m_oauthAppId after NormalizeAppIdentifier()
>   i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|0aeb5a99-dcc6-4208-9398-a4fc10272c6b@3a5e94a9-2edd-42b3-9fca-5ef76e45719f.
>   Now getting app principal info.
>
> decided that we need to do a POST to the app.
>
> App token requested from appredirect.aspx for site:
>   5998b5cd-6cef-41b4-b36a-eca33cbfbb03 but there was an error in
>   generating it.  This may be a case when we do not need a token or when
>   the app principal was not properly set up. 
>   LaunchUrl:https://apps.myCompany.nl/PCDocument/Create?SPHostUrl=https://bm.myCompany.nl&SPHostTitle=myCompany&SPAppWebUrl=""&SPLanguage=nl-NL&SPClientTag=1&SPProductNumber=15.0.4841.1000&SenderId=960DD4660 Exception Message:De app
>   i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|0aeb5a99-dcc6-4208-9398-a4fc10272c6b@3a5e94a9-2edd-42b3-9fca-5ef76e45719f
>   has no endpoint or endpoint is not valid.  Stacktrace:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AppRedirectPage.ValidateAndProcessRequest().
>   Since this is a nonfatal error, it will be sanitized and posted to the
>   app as part of the app launch.
>
> Getting Error Message for Exception Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException:
>   The app
>   i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|0aeb5a99-dcc6-4208-9398-a4fc10272c6b@3a5e94a9-2edd-42b3-9fca-5ef76e45719f
>   has no endpoint or endpoint is not valid.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AppRedirectPage.ValidateAndProcessRequest()
>
> Doing appredirect from appredirect.aspx: in site:
>   5998b5cd-6cef-41b4-b36a-eca33cbfbb03 with RedirectLaunchUrl:
>   https://apps.myCompany.nl/PCDocument/Create?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fbm%2EmyCompany%2Enl&SPHostTitle=myCompany&SPAppWebUrl=""&SPLanguage=nl%2DNL&SPClientTag=1&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4841%2E1000&SenderId=960DD4660

**UPDATE**

[Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=83691370617686141552) are my modified TokenHelper.cs and SharePointContext.cs files.

**UPDATE**

I was triggered by Sergei Sergeev to increase the outer token lifetime. I did some investigation and this is the fix. The outer token lifetime (10 minutes) needs to be higher than the HighTrustAccessTokenLifetime (12 hours). Another reason why it was not working in our situation, is because we save the SharePointHighTrustSamlContext in the session like they do for SharePointAcsContext and SharePointHighTrustContext. In this [example](https://lekman.codeplex.com/releases/view/611248) of Tobias Lekman the tokens will always recreated for each new request and you dont have a dependancy with the lifetime of the tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access token expires in 12hrs by default in high-trust (when using `TokenHelper.cs`). Session in 20min, but in that case `SharePointContext.cs` should renew it.

May be your custom logic affects this somehow.
My guess - try to adjust session expiration time to one hour for example (`web.config`):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**UPD**
Looking at the modified `SharePointContext.cs` it seems I found exact reason for your issue.
Take a look at the line `1178` in `SharePointContext.cs`:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10)
```

Your *user+add-in* token lifetime is only 10 minutes (besides your *add-in only* token, line `1150` is good). Put here `TokenLifetimeMinutes` instead of `10` and I think you are good to go.

Comment: What should happen after the default 20 minutes expiration? Should I expect the adfs login page?

Comment: `SharePointContext.cs` stores context information inside the Session. When it expires, it tries to renew it by forcing redirect to `AppRedirect.aspx`. `AppRedirect.aspx` in turns, redirects back to your page with context information.

Comment: I dont have this issue after 15 minutes. It looks like it is random. Sometimes 15, 20, 30, 45, 60 minutes etc.

Comment: How your remote app (MVC) is hosted? May be multiple web servers? If not, for me it looks like some issues with business logic inside code (as you said it's random).. caching doesn't work as expected or something.

Comment: I created manual a new web site in IIS. Created a self signed certificate. Created a https binding with hostname. I did this on the SP server. I have also a adfs domain controller server and a sql server. This is my development environment. We have also modified the tokenhelper.cs file to make it compatible with adfs authentication.

Comment: Any other idea Kai?

Comment: @Ola: not many. Your screen says the error is in `GetListByTitle` line. I tend to think this is something not correctly configured or issues with your business logic and\or token generation. As said, by default token expires in 12hrs, but you modified tokenhelper. Can you share your modified tokenhelper, may be that will give some clues..

Comment: I updated my post. There you can find a link to my modified tokenhelper.cs and sharepointcontext.cs

Comment: @Ola: please refer to my update

Comment: Thank you, I will modify it and test it for a while. I try to find some information about the outer and actor tokens. Do you know what these tokens means and why the lifetime needs to be in sync?

Comment: `Actor token` means add-in only token, without context of a user, `Outer token` holds also user context. If you modify something from code with `Outer token`, you will see in the UI smth like `"Modifed by YourAppName on behalf of UserName"`. In case of addin only there will be `"Modified by YourAppName"`. No need to sync lifetime for these tokens, but 10min is very small lifetime period. You can set any value you want, but I suggest to put value more than your authentication cookie expiration time. 12hrs should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, is there some blog post where I can find these information? Maybe some blog post with the best practice to make the SharePointContext.cs compatible with ADFS authentication. The only one I found was this: http://blog.lekman.com/2015/02/sharepoint-high-trust-apps-and-adfssaml.html. He is referencing to an example of the tokenhelper.cs and sharepointcontext.cs: https://lekman.codeplex.com/releases/view/611248

Comment: Actually there is no much information on this topic over internet (at least information I'm aware of). I know only about post from Wictor Wilen and that's it.

Comment: I found the issue. See update. The outer token lifetime (10 minutes) needs to be higher than the HighTrustAccessTokenLifetime (12 hours).

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase your token cache limit and token lifetime.

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.CookieLifetime = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 600
$sts.WindowsTokenLifetime = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 600
$sts.MaxApplicationTokenCacheItems = 100000
$sts.MaxLogonTokenCacheItems = 100000
$sts.MaxServiceTokenCacheItems = 100000
$sts.Update()
```

Make sure that you document what these values are before you change them and [research each value](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607549.aspx) to understand what they are and what changing the value means to your environment.

When I changed these values, it took about a day to take hold.  I assume the old values are cached but don't know how to force the cache to clear.

Comment: Why should I increase these settings? And why are the default values giving me this issue. I expect that the default values should working fine.

Comment: I'm not going to Google for you.  I clearly gave you a link explaining what these values do.

Comment: but is this a known issue and is this the solution, or is this just a workaround to increate the expired time?

Comment: I do not know if Microsoft knows about this or recognizes this as an issue.

Comment: James, did you ever have the same issue like me?

Comment: I had a similiar issue where the tokens within Office products were expiring and not allowing people to save back to SharePoint after the token expired.

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176552/upload-failed-you-are-required-to-sign-in-to-upload-your-changes-to-this-locati

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

I think your configuration could be the problem. You need to make sure you have a high trust created, so the provider hosted app can authenticate with SharePoint.

Take a look at these instructions to see if you missed something.

[Configure an environment to run your provider-hosted high trust apps in SharePoint 2013](http://www.appzinside.com/2015/03/13/configure-an-environment-to-run-your-provider-hosted-high-trust-apps-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Let me know if you need any help.

Jim